# Message 'archive type not supported'

Tags: installed-programs

I'm trying to install a translation program and when executing the file by double clicking on it, the message I got is 'could not open program because archive type not supported.

I've used windows all my life, and so far finding Ubuntu very confusing. Could anybody help, while keeping it simple?

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: Try just Rename the file from  original <filename> extension to <filename>.tar.

Once you done with this, use the below mentioned method in  command line 

tar <filename>.tar

Comment: @vembutech, filename extensions are entirely unnecessary; they are only there for the benefit of the human.

Comment: If as you say in a comment below it is a .tgz then there is no reason why Ubuntu wouldn't be able to open unless the file were corrupt. Try downloading it again and make sure you get the whole file (check the size corresponds to the information on your download site.) To install from .tgz see http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file. If you want to save yourself this technical headache you can still use the Software Centre as I suggested in my deleted post.

Comment: This is a valid question - some sites distribute .AppImage files, that generate that message. For example - http://www.openshot.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

If it's a zip you may need to install unzip first. If it's a rar you may need to install unrar.

If it was a .tar or .tar.gz you wouldn't get the error about "archive type not supported".

Rather than double click file, right click on it and choose uncompress. Like I said if it's a zip or rar, run the following commands first, or use software center.

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

Or

```
 sudo apt-get install unrar
```

One installed, again right click and you should see an uncompress option. Now with the right archive type installed it should uncompress.

Edit: what is the file extension by the way?

Update: Since the extension is .tgz you can either

```
 tar zxvf fileNameHere.tgz
```

From the command line, or as I said before, right click and select extract from file manager

Comment: the extension is .tgz

Comment: Assuming you didn't get figured out yet, from command line it would be tar zxvf fileName.tgz, but as I mentioned before, from file manager (nautilus) you should just be able to right click and extract